# what the "!" means in the iptable rule

Tags: linux, networking, bash, firewall, iptables

what the "!" means in the following iptable rule

```
iptables -I inacc ! -i br0 -p UDP --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
```

I think is related to the interface `br0`. I think it mean any interface except the `br0`

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are.
From "man iptables"

```
[!] -i, --in-interface name
          Name  of  an  interface  via  which  a packet was received (only for packets entering the INPUT, FORWARD and PREROUTING chains).  When the "!" argument is used before the interface name, the sense is inverted.  If the
          interface name ends in a "+", then any interface which begins with this name will match.  If this option is omitted, any interface name will match.
```